# Grouping flat xml using xslt (muenchian grouping), can't get it to group

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, filemaker, xslt-grouping

I spent quite some time trying to get muenchian grouping of the below xml to work but I can't get it to work. I tried a number of different ways so posting the most recent attempt probably just confuses anyone trying to help me. :-)

Xslt needs to be 1.0

Input file is invoice lines where "invoice header info" is duplicated for each line belonging to a particular invoice.

Grouping should be made in field _id, i e value in RESULTSET/ROW"/COL[12]/DATA (e. g. 'C82F1B47-9758-4D18-ABD7-80386385F6AD')

COL[21] through COL[27] are the different invoice lines for the invoice and as such should be listed line by line and under the respective invoice.

**Input xml (it is from Filemaker):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="01-22-2016" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 14.0.5"/>
    <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="Yyyy-m-d" LAYOUT="" NAME="fmStaben.fmp12" RECORDS="113" TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_MEMBER" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_MEDLEM_KSIFFER" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_FIRST_NAME" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_LAST_NAME" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_FIRST_PNAME" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_LAST_PNAME" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_ADDRESS1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_ADDRESS2" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_ZIP" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_CITY" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_STATE" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::_id" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_ORDERNR" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_POSTAGE" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_ORDER_TOTAL" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_DISCOUNT" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_MVA_AMOUNT" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_AMOUNT_TO_PAY" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_KID" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OrderHeader::OH_AMOUNT_MODUS" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_LINE" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_LTYPE" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_ART_NR" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_ART_TEXT" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_QUANTITY" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_PRICE" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="OL_TOTAL" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="6">
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="601">
            <COL>
                <DATA>109948</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>45</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JOHN</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JAMES</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2323 MAIN STREET</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>999 99</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>MAGIC KINGDOM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>C82F1B47-9758-4D18-ABD7-80386385F6AD</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>409949</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>3534534534517</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>7</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>010</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>99-131015DM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>WORLD CUP KIT 1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="602">
            <COL>
                <DATA>109948</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>45</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JOHN</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JAMES</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>2323 MAIN STREET</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>999 99</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>MAGIC KINGDOM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>C82F1B47-9758-4D18-ABD7-80386385F6AD</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>409949</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>3534534534517</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>7</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>020</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>99-140312DM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>WORLD CUP KIT 2</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="603">
            <COL>
                <DATA>049985</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>77</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>TEST</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>VON TEST</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>TESTPARENT</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>VON TEST</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>789 LEFT STREET</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>999 99</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>MAGIC KINGDOM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>5A2D83C6-ECEB-4636-968E-97DC6E5B1C8A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>409950</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>92350429953250</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>7</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>010</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>99-140312DM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>WORLD CUP KIT 3</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="605">
            <COL>
                <DATA>129984</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>15</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>CARL</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JANE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>4525 GREAT ROAD</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>999 99</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>MAGIC KINGDOM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>478E8CF0-7C93-4BE4-B314-FBCBDB5184F0</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>409951</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>92359999843251</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>7</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>020</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>99-1407156</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>150 FOOTBALL LEGENDS</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="606">
            <COL>
                <DATA>129984</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>15</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>CARL</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JANE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>4525 GREAT ROAD</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>999 99</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>MAGIC KINGDOM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>478E8CF0-7C93-4BE4-B314-FBCBDB5184F0</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>409951</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>92359999843251</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>7</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>030</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>99-140312DM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>WORLD CUP KIT 3</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="607">
            <COL>
                <DATA>129984</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>15</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>CARL</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>JANE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>DOE</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>4525 GREAT ROAD</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>999 99</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>MAGIC KINGDOM</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>478E8CF0-7C93-4BE4-B314-FBCBDB5184F0</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>409951</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>49,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>92359999843251</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>7</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>040</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>A</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>99-1402175</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>WORLD CUP KIT 2</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0,00</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

**Needed output xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Invoices>
    <Invoice>
        <Recipient>
            <MemberNo>109948</MemberNo>
            <CheckDigit>99</CheckDigit>
            <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
            <LastName>DOE</LastName>
            <GuardianFirstName>JAMES</GuardianFirstName>
            <GuardianLastName>DOE</GuardianLastName>
            <Address1>2323 MAIN STREET</Address1>
            <Address2/>
            <PostalCode>999 99</PostalCode>
            <City>MAGIC KINGDOM</City>
            <State/>
        </Recipient>
        <InvoiceHeader>
            <OrderNo>409949</OrderNo>               
            <Postage>49,00</Postage>
            <OrderTotal>49,00</OrderTotal>
            <Discount/>
            <VATAmount>0,00</VATAmount>
            <AmountToPay>49,00</AmountToPay>
            <PaymentReferenceNo>3534534534517</PaymentReferenceNo>
            <AmountModus>7</AmountModus>
        </InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <InvoiceLine>
                <LineNo>010</LineNo>
                <LineType>A</LineType>
                <ItemNo>99-131015DM</ItemNo>
                <ItemDescription>WORLD CUP KIT 1</ItemDescription>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>0,00</UnitPrice>
                <LineAmount>0,00</LineAmount>
            </InvoiceLine>
            <InvoiceLine>
                <LineNo>020</LineNo>
                <LineType>A</LineType>
                <ItemNo>99-140312DM</ItemNo>
                <ItemDescription>WORLD CUP KIT 2</ItemDescription>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>0,00</UnitPrice>
                <LineAmount>0,00</LineAmount>
            </InvoiceLine>
        </InvoiceLines>
    </Invoice> 
    <Invoice>
        <Recipient>
            <MemberNo>049985</MemberNo>
            <CheckDigit>77</CheckDigit>
            <FirstName>TEST</FirstName>
            <LastName>VON TEST</LastName>
            <GuardianFirstName>TESTPARENT</GuardianFirstName>
            <GuardianLastName>VON TEST</GuardianLastName>
            <Address1>789 LEFT STREET</Address1>
            <Address2/>
            <PostalCode>999 99</PostalCode>
            <City>MAGIC KINGDOM</City>
            <State/>
        </Recipient>
        <InvoiceHeader>
            <OrderNo>409950</OrderNo>               
            <Postage>49,00</Postage>
            <OrderTotal>49,00</OrderTotal>
            <Discount/>
            <VATAmount>0,00</VATAmount>
            <AmountToPay>49,00</AmountToPay>
            <PaymentReferenceNo>92350429953250</PaymentReferenceNo>
            <AmountModus>7</AmountModus>
        </InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <InvoiceLine>
                <LineNo>010</LineNo>
                <LineType/>
                <ItemNo>99-140312DM</ItemNo>
                <ItemDescription>WORLD CUP KIT 3</ItemDescription>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>0,00</UnitPrice>
                <LineAmount>0,00</LineAmount>
            </InvoiceLine>
        </InvoiceLines>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <Recipient>
            <MemberNo>129984</MemberNo>
            <CheckDigit>15</CheckDigit>
            <FirstName>CARL</FirstName>
            <LastName>DOE</LastName>
            <GuardianFirstName>JANE</GuardianFirstName>
            <GuardianLastName>DOE</GuardianLastName>
            <Address1>4525 GREAT ROAD</Address1>
            <Address2/>
            <PostalCode>999 99</PostalCode>
            <City>MAGIC KINGDOM</City>
            <State/>
        </Recipient>
        <InvoiceHeader>
            <OrderNo>409951</OrderNo>               
            <Postage>49,00</Postage>
            <OrderTotal>49,00</OrderTotal>
            <Discount/>
            <VATAmount>0,00</VATAmount>
            <AmountToPay>49,00</AmountToPay>
            <PaymentReferenceNo>92359999843251</PaymentReferenceNo>
            <AmountModus>7</AmountModus>
        </InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <InvoiceLine>
                <LineNo>020</LineNo>
                <LineType>A</LineType>
                <ItemNo>99-1407156</ItemNo>
                <ItemDescription>150 FOOTBALL LEGENDS</ItemDescription>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>0,00</UnitPrice>
                <LineAmount>0,00</LineAmount>
            </InvoiceLine>
            <InvoiceLine>
                <LineNo>030</LineNo>
                <LineType>A</LineType>
                <ItemNo>99-140312DM</ItemNo>
                <ItemDescription>WORLD CUP KIT 3</ItemDescription>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>0,00</UnitPrice>
                <LineAmount>0,00</LineAmount>
            </InvoiceLine>
            <InvoiceLine>
                <LineNo>040</LineNo>
                <LineType>A</LineType>
                <ItemNo>99-1402175</ItemNo>
                <ItemDescription>WORLD CUP KIT 2</ItemDescription>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <UnitPrice>0,00</UnitPrice>
                <LineAmount>0,00</LineAmount>
            </InvoiceLine>
        </InvoiceLines>
    </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

**Xlst that I usually use as a base to get the values from the input xml. I used it on several other occasions when I didn't need to group the data (and formating of output was a bit different):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <Invoices>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW" />
    </Invoices>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
        <Invoice>
            <Recipient>
                <MemberNo>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[1]" />
                </MemberNo>
                <CheckDigit>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[2]" />
                </CheckDigit>
                <FirstName>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[3]" />
                </FirstName>
                <LastName>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[4]" />
                </LastName>
                <GuardianFirstName>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[5]" />
                </GuardianFirstName>
                <GuardianLastName>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[6]" />
                </GuardianLastName>
                <Address1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[7]" />
                </Address1>
                <Address2>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[8]" />
                </Address2>
                <PostalCode>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[9]" />
                </PostalCode>
                <City>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[10]" />
                </City>
                <State>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[11]" />
                </State>
            </Recipient>
            <InvoiceHeader>
                <OrderNo>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[12]" />
                </OrderNo>              
                <Postage>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[13]" />
                </Postage>
                <OrderTotal>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[14]" />
                </OrderTotal>
                <Discount>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[15]" />
                </Discount>
                <VATAmount>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[16]" />
                </VATAmount>
                <AmountToPay>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[17]" />
                </AmountToPay>
                <PaymentReferenceNo>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[18]" />
                </PaymentReferenceNo>
                <AmountModus>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[19]" />
                </AmountModus>
            </InvoiceHeader>        
            <InvoiceLines>
                <InvoiceLine>
                    <LineNo>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[20]" />
                    </LineNo>
                    <LineType>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[21]" />
                    </LineType>
                    <ItemNo>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[22]" />
                    </ItemNo>
                    <ItemDescription>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[23]" />
                    </ItemDescription>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[24]" />
                    </Quantity>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[25]" />
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <LineAmount>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[26]" />
                    </LineAmount>
                </InvoiceLine>
            </InvoiceLines>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- the key indexes the METADATA fields by their position -->
    <xsl:key 
name="kMetaData" 
match="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" 
use="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1" 
/>   

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_MEMBER -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_MEDLEM_KSIFFER -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[2]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template> 

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_FIRST_NAME -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[3]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_LAST_NAME -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[4]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_FIRST_PNAME -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[5]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_LAST_PNAME -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[6]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_ADDRESS1 -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[7]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_ADDRESS2 -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[8]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_ZIP -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[9]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_CITY -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[10]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_STATE -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[11]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::_id -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[12]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_ORDERNO -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[13]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>     

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_POSTAGE -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[14]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_ORDER_TOTAL -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[15]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_DISCOUNT -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[16]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_MVA_AMOUNT -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[17]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_AMOUNT_TO_PAY -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[18]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_KID -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[19]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OrderHeader::OH_AMOUNT_MODUS -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[20]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_LINE -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[21]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_LTYPE -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[22]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_ART_NR -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[23]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_ART_TEXT -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[24]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_QUANTITY -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[25]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_PRICE -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[26]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- OL_TOTAL -->
    <xsl:template match="fmp:COL[27]">
        <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks you in advance to anyone beeing so kind as to take time to help me. :-)
//Freppan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given that you know the item you want to group by it should not be that difficult to define your key `<xsl:key name="group" match="fmp:ROW" use="fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA"/>` and use it:

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="fmp:ROW" use="fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <Invoices>
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA)[1])]"
        />
    </Invoices>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
    <Invoice>
        <Recipient>
            <MemberNo>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[1]"/>
            </MemberNo>
            <CheckDigit>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[2]"/>
            </CheckDigit>
            <FirstName>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[3]"/>
            </FirstName>
            <LastName>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[4]"/>
            </LastName>
            <GuardianFirstName>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[5]"/>
            </GuardianFirstName>
            <GuardianLastName>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[6]"/>
            </GuardianLastName>
            <Address1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[7]"/>
            </Address1>
            <Address2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[8]"/>
            </Address2>
            <PostalCode>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[9]"/>
            </PostalCode>
            <City>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[10]"/>
            </City>
            <State>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[11]"/>
            </State>
        </Recipient>
        <InvoiceHeader>
            <OrderNo>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[13]"/>
            </OrderNo>
            <Postage>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[14]"/>
            </Postage>
            <OrderTotal>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[15]"/>
            </OrderTotal>
            <Discount>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[16]"/>
            </Discount>
            <VATAmount>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[17]"/>
            </VATAmount>
            <AmountToPay>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[18]"/>
            </AmountToPay>
            <PaymentReferenceNo>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[19]"/>
            </PaymentReferenceNo>
            <AmountModus>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[20]"/>
            </AmountModus>
        </InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceLines>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('group', fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA)">
                <InvoiceLine>
                    <LineNo>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[21]"/>
                    </LineNo>
                    <LineType>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[22]"/>
                    </LineType>
                    <ItemNo>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[23]"/>
                    </ItemNo>
                    <ItemDescription>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[24]"/>
                    </ItemDescription>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[25]"/>
                    </Quantity>
                    <UnitPrice>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[26]"/>
                    </UnitPrice>
                    <LineAmount>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[27]"/>
                    </LineAmount>
                </InvoiceLine>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </InvoiceLines>
    </Invoice>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I reused your code (had to increment some positional predicates), I would consider cleaning up all those `<xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL[N]"/>` to simply use `<xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[N]/fmp:DATA"/>` however, as in this case the pushing the processing to a template does not really achieve some transformation.

Comment: Thanks, work perfectly. I really appreciate the help. I also took your advice on cleaning up the code.

Comment: @Freppan, This solution is superior to any solution that uses extension functions. Always go for 100% portable XSLT code. When using extension functions one is bound to a particular vendor, programming language, or even version of both the vendor's XSLT processor, and the function library. And, if you are using extension functions when there is a pure XSLT solution, you'd probably be better off not using XSLT at all. Don't believe "specialists", who advocate extension functions when pure and efficient XSLT solutions exist.

Comment: If I could downvote a comment I would; that's a ridiculous argument and based on nothing but a personal vendetta against @michael.hor257k. If an environment hosting XSLT has extension functions readily available, use whatever suits your needs best, they're available for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Muenchian grouping if you're doing the XSL transformation while exporting from FileMaker. You can take advantage of the [EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) that FileMaker's XSLT engine supports:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" 
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="group" match="fmp:ROW" use="fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA" />

<xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <Invoices>
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW/fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA)">
            <Invoice>
                <Recipient>
                    <MemberNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </MemberNo>
                    <CheckDigit>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </CheckDigit>
                    <FirstName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[3]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </FirstName>
                    <LastName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </LastName>
                    <GuardianFirstName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[5]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </GuardianFirstName>
                    <GuardianLastName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </GuardianLastName>
                    <Address1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[7]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </Address1>
                    <Address2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </Address2>
                    <PostalCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </PostalCode>
                    <City>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </City>
                    <State>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[11]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </State>
                </Recipient>
               <InvoiceHeader>
                    <OrderNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </OrderNo>              
                    <Postage>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[13]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </Postage>
                    <OrderTotal>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[14]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </OrderTotal>
                    <Discount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[15]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </Discount>
                    <VATAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[16]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </VATAmount>
                    <AmountToPay>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[17]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </AmountToPay>
                    <PaymentReferenceNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[18]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </PaymentReferenceNo>
                    <AmountModus>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[19]/fmp:DATA" />
                    </AmountModus>
                </InvoiceHeader>        
                <InvoiceLines>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('group', .)" >
                       <InvoiceLine>
                            <LineNo>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[20]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </LineNo>
                            <LineType>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[21]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </LineType>
                            <ItemNo>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[22]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </ItemNo>
                            <ItemDescription>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[23]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </ItemDescription>
                            <Quantity>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[24]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </Quantity>
                            <UnitPrice>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[25]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </UnitPrice>
                            <LineAmount>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[26]/fmp:DATA" />
                            </LineAmount>
                        </InvoiceLine>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </InvoiceLines>
            </Invoice> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Invoices>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution works just as well as the first one. Thanks. Filemakers support for EXSLT is very good to know and may come in handy in the future.

Comment: @Freppan Just keep in mind that only *some* EXSLT functions are supported.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Is there a list of EXSLT functions supported by Filemaker?

Comment: @NicolaiKant I have such list, but I cannot post it in a comment. Start a new question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks. Will do